# Exponential decay and growth oscillations at beginning and end of Fourier transform of data

Tags: fourier-transform, signal-processing, noise

I have some data from an photo-detector, which I think should correspond to white noise, but when I plot the Fourier transform of the data, I get a plot with exponential decay at the beginning and exponential growth at the end (Instead of the flat plot I expect). What does this mean (if anything)? [image: Fourier Transform (in blue) of Data (in green)]

Comment: It's probably spectral leakage. Try subtracting the mean of the data from the whole data set before doing the Fourier transform. If that doesn't work, please provide the data *and* the code you used to analyze it. Without that, we can't really help. Also, you say exponential decay, but did you actually check that?

Comment: Most software packages return the "symmetric" FFT spectrum. Therefore, I suspect that you simple chose the wrong presentation. In order to check this generate a simple known signal, like y(t) = sin(2*t), and use it to check your code. Do you get the correct FFT?